# How to use glVertexPointer() and glDrawArrays with a array of GLint's correctly to draw quads?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been trying to optimize my drawing code for a model visualizer i am working on, here is the old solution I used before:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
for (int i = 0; i < C.vertices_prepared.size(); i+=12) {
                glVertex3i(C.vertices_prepared[i], C.vertices_prepared[i+1], C.vertices_prepared[i+2]);
                glVertex3i(C.vertices_prepared[i+3], C.vertices_prepared[i+4], C.vertices_prepared[i+5]);
                glVertex3i(C.vertices_prepared[i+6], C.vertices_prepared[i+7], C.vertices_prepared[i+8]);
                glVertex3i(C.vertices_prepared[i+9], C.vertices_prepared[i+10], C.vertices_prepared[i+11]);
            }
glEnd();
```

This worked fine for a while, but it's really slow with huge models. I thought that maybe switching to glDrawArrays would make it faster. My new solution is:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, C.vertices_prepared.data());
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, C.vertices_prepared.size() / 3);
glEnd();
```

But this just doesn't work at all. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an invalid `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` operation error. Only a few operations are allowed within a [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence. It is used to specify a vertices with [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml). You don't need `glBegin`/`glEnd` at all when you use fixed function attributes and drawing with `glDrawArrays`. However enable and disable the `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`:

```cpp
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, C.vertices_prepared.data());
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, C.vertices_prepared.size() / 3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem, I had no idea you had to do it that way, this solution has also has managed to reduce the CPU usage from 9% to just 1%. Thanks for the help.